# Cocos2d spritesheets and animation

Tags: ios, flash, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I have a bit of a problem that I need help with. I have a sprite I need animated, but the sprite is 600x600 with 25 frames this becomes quite a large spritesheet, infact bigger then the iPhone will allow. What would be a way to get around this limitation? Animate in flash and export for cocos2d? is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shrink it down. Why would you even need such an big sprite?

Or add the frames individually. (Less efficient)

Answer (score 0):

For  [How to use animations and sprite-sheets in `cocos2d`](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32045/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-2-x) Read this is best documentation.

Any image displayed by cocos2d will have to fit within those dimensions as cocos2d, uses OpenGL and all images must be loaded into texture memory.

I’m not sure if some other API gives you a way to load larger images.

For more information [read this discussion.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/large-animations-with-cocos2d/)

Answer (score 0):

when you make sprite sheet using Texture Packer make .pvr.ccz file instead of output file .png , it will reduce file size.you can also use to load this texture on RGB_4444 texture.